# Laravel eloquent query with double entries, group by dosn't work

Tags: sql, laravel, percona, heidisql

I build a query in Laravel-6.x but get duplicate entries.

```php
public function get()
{


    $catArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45'];

    $platformArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'];

    $regionArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'];

    $languageArr = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26'];


    return Product::join('category_product', 'category_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->join('product_region', 'product_region.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->join('language_product', 'language_product.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->whereIn('category_product.category_id', $catArr)
        ->whereIn('products.platform_id', $platformArr)
        ->whereIn('product_region.region_id', $regionArr)
        ->whereIn('language_product.language_id', $languageArr)
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->paginate(18);
}
```

It's a simial SQL statement

```
SELECT * from `products` inner join `category_product` on `category_product`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` inner join `product_region` on `product_region`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` inner join `language_product` on `language_product`.`product_id` = `products`.`id` where `category_product`.`category_id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and `products`.`platform_id` IN (10) and `product_region`.`region_id` IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and `language_product`.`language_id` IN (26) LIMIT 20
```

I think I must add GROUP BY. But than HeidiSQL returns a error :

```
Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'shopdb.products.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O6jB.jpg)

Any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT DISTINCT(*)`?

Comment: Or just change your `sql_mode`

Answer (score 1):

Because it is the problem about `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` in your mysql

There are few modes about `sql_mode`

Try to change your `sql_mode`

### Set it Locally

```
set sql_mode ='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

### Set it global

```
set @@global.sql_mode ='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Or change `my.cnf` file:

Add this line below under `[mysqld]` and `[mysql]`

```
SET sql_mode ='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

and restart mysql.

**PS: Another problems with your code. Don't select all fields from all those tables, it costs times, and the last table's `id` will cover the previous id. Select those fields what you want, if the name is duplicated, use `AS` to another name**

```php
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->selectRaw('products.*, category_product.id AS cp_id')
        ->paginate(18);
```

### Use ANY_VALUE

Or you can use any_value to your column:

```php
        ->groupBy('products.id')
        ->selectRaw('ANY_VALUE(products.id),..., category_product.id AS cp_id')
        ->paginate(18);
```

### Disabled Strict Mode

Or you can disabled strict mode to config/database.php

```php
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            ...
            'strict' => false,
        ],
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I edit the sql_mode on my mysql server from putty. I removed 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER'.  >> set @@sql_mode 
='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';  << Is the right command

Comment: @Maaaxi It seems ok. The important thing is remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, You can try it. It's just locally command.

Comment: @Maaaxi Before you run that cmd, you can input `SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;` or 
`SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` to see what it is originally.